# How do I set where a string starts and ends in python?

Tags: python, string, serial-port, slice

I am working on a project for work, and to get it to work I need to capture data from over a serial port, put it into string form, and look for two key words in the string. the two words I'm am looking for are "PASS" and "2X400MHz".

At work we have an automated RAM tester and I would like to automate the sorting process for the RAM that passes by using an Arduino. In order to do this I need to monitor the data that comes out of the RAM tester via serial port and look for the speed of the RAM being tested, and the results of the test (PASS or FAIL). Once I create a string with the necessary information I will have python write to the arduino over serial and arduino will take care of all the sorting.

The reason I am stuck, and what makes this so hard is that the data that comes over the serial port varies in length according to if the RAM passes or fails instantly, halfway, or near the end of the test. The test is usually around 52 seconds for a 2GB module and 32 seconds for a 1GB module. As the module is testing the data that comes over the serial line is the name of the test being run and a timer that counts up by the second, when the test is over (failed or passed) all of the data on the Module's SPD chip is dumped over the serial line along with the word "PASS" or "FAIL". The timer counter is what is making the amount of data per test different depending on where it fails that is why I want to make a string of only the SPD data since it contains only the data that has significance to me.

I have used a serial monitoring program to capture a sample to show the data I am working with.The SPD data I am interested in is near the bottom, the rest of the data above it is just the timer. The data near the bottom is always the same besides the SPD data (speed, configuration, serial number). I am hoping there is a way to have python use one word that always show up before and after the SPD data to start and stop creating a string, that way the string will only be the SPD data and will exclude the counter data.

`..Waiting for Handler Start ....Åþ....[ Esc. ]Åþe.ÅþE.ÅþE.Åþ.*..L001: wk_addr                    [00:00]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ.*..L001: wk_data                    [00:00]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ.*..L001: Mats                       [00:01]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:02]Åþ...![00:02]Åþ...![00:03]Åþ...![00:03]Åþ...![00:03]Åþ...![00:04]Åþ...![00:05]Åþ...![00:05]Åþ...![00:06]Åþ...![00:06]Åþ...![00:07]Åþ...![00:07]Åþ...![00:08]Åþ...![00:09]Åþ...![00:09]Åþ...![00:10]Åþ.*..L001: Mar_X                      [00:10]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:11]Åþ...![00:11]Åþ...![00:12]Åþ...![00:12]Åþ...![00:12]Åþ...![00:13]Åþ...![00:14]Åþ...![00:14]Åþ...![00:15]Åþ...![00:15]Åþ...![00:16]Åþ...![00:16]Åþ...![00:17]Åþ...![00:18]Åþ...![00:18]Åþ...![00:19]Åþ...![00:19]Åþ...![00:20]Åþ...![00:20]Åþ...![00:21]Åþ.*..L001: Mar_C                      [00:21]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:22]Åþ...![00:22]Åþ...![00:23]Åþ...![00:23]Åþ...![00:24]Åþ...![00:24]Åþ...![00:25]Åþ...![00:25]Åþ...![00:26]Åþ...![00:26]Åþ...![00:27]Åþ...![00:28]Åþ...![00:28]Åþ...![00:29]Åþ...![00:29]Åþ...![00:30]Åþ...![00:31]Åþ...![00:31]Åþ...![00:32]Åþ...![00:32]Åþ...![00:32]Åþ...![00:33]Åþ...![00:34]Åþ...![00:34]Åþ...![00:35]Åþ...![00:35]Åþ...![00:36]Åþ...![00:37]Åþ...![00:37]Åþ...![00:37]Åþ...![00:38]Åþ...![00:39]Åþ.*..L001: Mar_Y                      [00:39]Åþ....[Cancel]ÅþA'Åþ...![00:39]Åþ...![00:40]Åþ...![00:40]Åþ...![00:41]Åþ...![00:41]Åþ...![00:42]Åþ...![00:42]Åþ...![00:43]Åþ...![00:43]Åþ...![00:44]Åþ...![00:44]Åþ...![00:45]Åþ...![00:45]Åþ...![00:46]Åþ...![00:46]Åþ...![00:47]Åþ...![00:47]Åþ...![00:48]Åþ...![00:48]Åþ...![00:49]Åþ...![00:49]Åþ...![00:50]Åþ...![00:50]Åþ...![00:51]Åþ...![00:51]Åþ...![00:52]Åþ...![00:52]Åþ...![00:53]Åþe.Åþ}...ÅþE.Åþa¡ÅþD.Åþ"0.Module..: ****DDR2 256Mx72 2GB 2R(8)@2x400MHZ 1.8V.Åþ"...(Tested at 2x400MHz).Åþ".Addr.(rowxcol.).: 14 x 10.Åþ".Data (rankxbit).:  2 x 72.Åþ".Internal Banks.:  8.Åþ""Burst.: Mode=Sequential, Length=8.Åþ"*AC parameters.: CL=5, AL=0, Trcd=5, Trp=5.Åþ".S/N from SPD.: a128f4f3.Åþ".Test Loop #.: 1.Åþ"..## PASS:   Loop 1 ##.Åþ"..Elapsed Time.: 00:00:53.448.Åþa¢Åþc.............H..ÿÿÿÿ"ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ...s-(U.?€.....".. Åþ@.ÅþE.Åþ....**PASS - L001 @2x400MHZÅþ...![00:53]Åþ....Transmit Results ...Åþa¡ÅþD.Åþ"0.Module..: DDR2 256Mx72 2GB 2R(8)@2x400MHZ 1.8V.Åþ"...(Tested at 2x400MHz).Åþ".Addr.(rowxcol.).: 14 x 10.Åþ".Data (rankxbit).:  2 x 72.Åþ".Internal Banks.:  8.Åþ""Burst.: Mode=Sequential, Length=8.Åþ"*AC parameters.: CL=5, AL=0, Trcd=5, Trp=5.Åþ".S/N from SPD.: .Åþ".Test Loop #.: 1.Åþ"..## PASS:   Loop 1 ##.Åþ"..Elapsed Time.: 00:00:53.448.Åþa¢Åþ@.Åþ.** ..**`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems what you're looking for is the .find() method of String. Using that and the wonderful utility that is Python's string slices, you can easily accomplish what you're after.

As an example:

```
# Our string with the text that we're after.
blob = "filler text filler text BEGIN This is what we're after. END filler text."

# Use .find() to find the first occurrence of two given substrings.
start = blob.find("BEGIN")
end = blob.find("END")

# Our result will be: 'BEGIN This is what we're after. '
result = blob[start:end]
```

If you wanted to take it a step further, you could add the len() value of start to the string slice in order to prevent BEGIN being added and remove leading and trailing spaces with blob.strip()

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! this looks to be exactly what I need. I wont be able to test it until I get back in town and back to work, but the way you describe how it works is spot on to what I need.